# Why does neo4j convert my number to Double with point Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-driver

I am using `neo4j-driver` inside node js and so far it worked great! But now I have a Date Stamp, which looks `1634717983`  when I try to create a node with date property in neo4j it converts the number to double which looks `Double(1.634718e+06)`. Here is my code

```
nodes[0].createdAt = 1634717983

const createUserCyper = `
    UNWIND $nodes as node 
    CREATE (a:Node {
      id: node.id, 
      name: node.name, 
      createdAt: datetime({epochSeconds:node.createdAt / 1000, nanosecond: 23}), 
  })`;
  const result = await session.run(
    createUserCyper,
    {nodes},
  );
```

My question is how should I explain to neo4j not to convert my number ?

Comment: I think all javascript number values passed as parameters will be treated as Float type. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#numbers-and-the-integer-type

Comment: Would it make sense to use the DateTime temporal type instead? https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/4.3/class/lib6/temporal-types.js~DateTime.html

Comment: @HåkanLöfqvist I mad it by this. datetime({epochSeconds:toInteger(node.createdAt) / 1000, nanosecond: 23}), 
but could you provide an example of using DateTime ? Probably it's better solution and can be the answer.